# Как WebView заставить авторизоваться на сайте

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. В приложении реализовал ввод логина и пароля, для авторизации. И после ввода этих данных сразу вызываю другой Activity с WebView .
Вопрос. Как в WebView передать эти данные, чтобы он послал POST и не пришлось вводить данные для авторизации через сам WebView.
И возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Кому принадлежит страница, открываемая во WebView? Вам?

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin да, мне

Comment: Самый простой вариант - открывать страницу, передавая туда параметры в querystring. Например: `http://example.com/auth?log=base64login&pwd=base64password`. На стороне страницы - парсить   querystring, получить оттуда данные и кидать на пост-запрос. Не самое красивое решение, но рабочее 100%

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin хорошая идея. спасибо.

Comment: Если сессия запоминается в куках, можно заранее сформировать правильный кук в js.